# Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation with async await

Tags: swift, async-await

I'm working on converting some code to async/await and getting the error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation

at the `doSomething()`. If I remove the portion of the code that is `await withTaskGroup` the error goes away.

I've also tried doing `(someURL: URL?)` in the completion handler and no change.

```swift
private func someFunction() {
    SomeManagerClass.sharedInstance().doSomething() { someURL in
        // do something with someURL
        await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { [weak self] group in
            // do some more work
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: first issue is you are using await inside a closure which does not support async/await. First convert `SomeManagerClass.sharedInstance().doSomething()` to support async await, and then you can put the whole thing inside a Task closure or make `someFunction` async

Comment: To connect a completion handler to `async/await` you need a `Continuation` rather than a `TaskGroup`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by breaking out the async code into its own function

```swift
private func newFunction() async -> URL? {
    return await withCheckedContinuation { url in
        SomeManagerClass.sharedInstance().doSomething() { someURL in
            continuation.resume(returning: url)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m upvoting because this is the right technique, but if you were wondering why this was downvoted, it was likely because this is a “code-only” answer, which is generally discouraged. It is best to explain the code snippet, namely to explain why/how the code answers the question.

Comment: Ok thank you for the feedback Rob. I'll go ahead and do that.